# Issue to load the static folder in cPanel

Tags: cpanel

my project is working fine on local but on live server(godaddy) its not getting static folder. urls are just, i create the seperate folder as static and also create css, js, images folder created and extention files insert in static folder , while inserting in cpanel {% load static %}
{%static 'images/dummy.jpg'%} it's the proper path but it's not working on cpanel . my project is default settings.py , need to change on settings.py ? to load the static ?

i need the clear step to solve the issue

.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.